# Avoid npm refresh after every deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a Node.js website hosted on Heroku, that I deploy with git.
I use several node modules, referenced in package.json; is there a way to prevent Heroku to 'refresh' them each time I deploy a new version of the code, as long as package.json did not change?

Note: this would be especially useful for 'native' modules, whose compilation takes a bit of time; for .js-only modules, I was successful removing them from package.json, and adding their node_modules/ folder in the git repo.

Comment: Agreed, a bit of build caching would be great. But I understand it can get tricky quickly; no caching is still better than incorrect caching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the official Heroku Node.js Buildpack.

We have a new version of the buildpack in beta that features caching support, designed specifically for the use case you described above. You can read more about it at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/tree/diet#about-this-refactor

Eventually this will become the default Node.js buildpack on Heroku, but if you want to use it now you'll need to set the BUILPACK_URL config var explicitly:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#diet -a my-node-app
git commit -am "fakeout" --allow-empty
git push heroku
```

Comment: Seems to be the default now

Comment: its 2015... does heroku still rebuild all dependencies?

Comment: We have a setup with a ./node_modules dir AND a ./client/node_modules dir since we deploy a CRA project as a child of the server.  Is it possible to also somehow cache the node_modules deployed to the ./client directory?

Comment: Hi Zeke. Does docker recognise when new layers are different from previous and only rebuild any new layers, and if no new layers, simply use the last (unchanged) image? Could something similar be possible on heroku? (ps I'm not node, i'm running R and rails, but same principles would apply I suspect). For reference, and R shiny build is around 214MB (!). So any efficiencies would be impactful

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there has recently been progress by David Dollar at the [heroku-buildpack-nodejs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/43).

In short:

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-nodejs`

See answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535675/1318839

Answer (score 0):

You can add both .js and native npm packages and still avoid the "refresh", (at least the re-downloading part of the "refresh".)

Include the native  packages to your `node_modules/` directory. When you deploy to Heroku,  `npm install` will skip the downloading of the package.  `npm rebuild` is also run. It will take some time to re-compile the native packages, but it should be very bearable unless you have tons of native packages.

*Sidenote*: [Heroku doc on what Heroku does when you push a nodejs app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior).

*Sidenote:* The `npm rebuild` is needed because there "are mysterious failures that can happen between [node and native code modules after a node upgrade](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#redis---a-nodejs-redis-client)".

Answer (score 0):

Clone the Heroku node.js buildpack, and modify it to remove the `rebuild` command.

The command is currently run here:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile#L180 , but that's bound to change.

You can run create an app that uses your own buildpack by modifying the command below to match your own repo:
`heroku create --buildpack http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git`

Or change the buildpack of an existing app with:
`heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git`

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I need to include private repos in my app/build pack. So I wonder if this will have the same issue, if I must keep the buildpack private.