# Speed up deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, npm

Heroku is great.  But every time I deploy, Heroku seems to like to redownload and rebuild all the packages.  With `socket.io` and `mailparser` this is taking around 3 minutes.

Is there a way to speed up the deployment process?  Is there a way to tell Heroku that it can cache these items?  Or can I upload prebuilt `node_modules`?

Comment: The [build-pack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) (which is code that transforms your source code to what gets deployed on Heroku) should already be caching `node_modules` between builds. At least it says so in the README. Are you sure that this is what's slowing down your build?

Comment: @friism I guess they use standard NPM caching, so the modules still have to be unpacked, copied and, most importantly, recompiled after each push. If you have modules with a promiscuous dependency tree or depending on C++ extensions (mongodb, socket.io, etc) it takes some time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like as of today Heroku is finally caching the `node_modules` folder!

> -----> Deleting 6 files matching .slugignore patterns.
>
> -----> Node.js app detected
>
> -----> Requested node range:  0.10.x
>
> -----> Resolved node version: 0.10.22
>
> -----> Downloading and installing node
>
> **-----> Restoring node_modules from cache**
>
> -----> Installing dependencies
>
> -----> Pruning unused dependencies
>
> **-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds**
>
> -----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts

Build time is like 3 seconds for me now.

Comment: yup I had the same experience today as well.  Will it always cache them or will it know when they update automatically now?

Comment: I don't have a source, but I imagine this: If they simply copy the `node_modules` folder into the project and run `npm update`, it will only update the parts that need an update. So basically npm already handles this well. That's the beauty of npm, it maps the whole dependency tree to the filesystem.

Comment: After a week I can confirm that every time I update a module dependency and push to heroku that only this one module is fetched from the npm registry. Is so much faster than before.

Comment: Rather than `npm update` as @Prinzhorn suggests, they are likely running `npm install` which will only install what is missing. Then they are running `npm prune` which will remove modules which are not listed in the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I did to speed up process was to add .slugignore file to the main folder and add all the files and folders I did not want to run the app.

Sample content of .slugignore file:
working
mockups
*.psd
*.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into the same problem.

Some discussion here about caching the `node_modules` folder: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/37

Another idea: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/25

---

I'm thinking about a few solutions right now.

1. **Check in `node_modules` in a separate branch**: The core Node.js maintainers actually recommend checking in the `node_modules` folder into source control (for apps, not libs). I don't like this. A way to get around it though might be to have a separate `production` branch with a different `.gitignore` file that doesn't ignore `node_modules`. When you want to deploy, just do a rebase from your master and `node_modules` will be checked in. At least this keeps your master branch free from dependencies.
2. **Add a `preinstall` script to `package.json` to download compressed dependency zip**: You could also add a pre-push git hook to bundle up your dependencies and upload them to S3. This would probably be too slow though.
3. **Modify the `heroku-buildpack-nodejs`**: Integrate the outstanding pull request with `node_modules` caching:

   `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/opdemand/buildpack-nodejs.git`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question (see [Avoid npm refresh after every deployment on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698652/avoid-npm-refresh-after-every-deployment-on-heroku)).

Heroku forces a download/build/etc. sequence because they need to start an app with a 'blank slate': to clean previous undeleted files, when they move your app to another server, when you assign new web dynos, etc.

The issue is clearly with native packages, and recompilation. For all js-only packages, I commit them with my project, and remove them from package.json. It gains a few seconds, but not that much.

I should definitely be possible to pre-compile and commit native modules (I successfully run wkhtml2pdf on Heroku, for instance, with a binary compiled for linux-amd64), if you get access to a Linux box (or VM) with the same configuration - as of today, `Linux [...] 2.6.32-350-ec2 #57-Ubuntu SMP [...] x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Though I would not recommend it as a definitive solution, since it is likely to break some day - It does not seem to me that heroku guarantees the platform an app runs onto.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there has recently been progress at the [heroku-buildpack-nodejs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/43).

Once the pull request is merged, you can add

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs`

to your [heroku environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

For now, David Dollar's forked repository is available at

`https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-nodejs`

With this as your `BUILDPACK_URL` it should cache the npm modules.
I tried it with node.js 0.10.5a, npm version: 1.3.5 and npm_modules in `.gitignore`. Tt seems to work fine so far!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this branch of the new Heroku Node.js buildpack, now in beta, which supports node_modules caching between builds:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/tree/diet

To use it:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#diet -a my-node-app
git commit -am "fakeout" --allow-empty
git push heroku
```