# How to prevent Heroku from installing node modules on every deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-toolbelt

When deploying a Node.js app to Heroku, there is a long wait for node modules to be installed on every deploy.

How do I optionally specify if Node modules should be reinstalled on each deploy?

This question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698652/avoid-npm-refresh-after-every-deployment-on-heroku` was asked a long time ago, but doesn't seem to address the issue.